# дана 2 массива нужно найти уникальные элементы и открыть третий массив.javascript

Tags: javascript

```
Array.prototype.diff = function(a) {
   return this.filter(function(i){return a.indexOf(i) < 0;});
};

let arr1 = [ 1, 5, 0, 8, 4, 6 , 9, 2, 3];
   arr2 = [1, 7, 8, 4, 6 , 2, 10];
var result = arr1.diff(arr2);
console.info(result);
```

Comment: Приведите пример ответа и ваш код. Мы обязательно его исправим.

Comment: Array.prototype.diff = function(a) {
   return this.filter(function(i){return a.indexOf(i) < 0;});
};

let arr1 = [ 1, 5, 0, 8, 4, 6 , 9, 2, 3];
   arr2 = [1, 7, 8, 4, 6 , 2, 10];
var result = arr1.diff(arr2);
console.info(result);

Comment: Посместите ваш комментарий в вопрос.

Comment: arr[7,10,3,9,0,5,] ответ такой должен быть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из нужного ответа, делаю вывод, что надо найти все уникальные значение из двух массивов. Сделать это можно так:

```js
Array.prototype.diff = function(a) {
  return [
    ...a.filter(i => this.indexOf(i) < 0), 
    ...this.filter(i => a.indexOf(i) < 0)
  ];
}

const arr1 = [1, 5, 0, 8, 4, 6, 9, 2, 3];
const arr2 = [1, 7, 8, 4, 6, 2, 10];

console.log(arr1.diff(arr2)); // [7, 10, 3, 9, 0, 5]
```

P.S. Хотел придумат алгоритм побыстрее и наткнулся на [похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript).